# using a drop-down list to select a value for a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Using MVC 4, Razor

I have a model like this:

```
public class Device
{
[Required]
public string TYPE {get; set;}
}
```

I need to get the value of TYPE from user in a form, but they are limited to 3 values, "A" , "B" , "C"

How do i enforce/do this in the View section?

Right now I have: 

 `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.TYPE)`  

but this will allow the user to write in anything they want

Comment: You say your wanting to use a Drop-Down List but your using an EditorTemplate...Is this what your wanting?  If so, can we see your EditorTemplate?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TYPE, 
new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem { Text = "A", Value = "A" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "B", Value = "B" },
        new SelectListItem { Text = "C", Value = "C" },
    })
```

Comment: Thanks this is simple and exactly what was needed!

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using a `DropDownListFor` and letting the user select from the available values. First create an enum for TYPE:

```
public enum PickType
{
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
}
```

Then in your View:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.TYPE, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(PickType))))
```